# How to fetch data from browser cache?

Tags: javascript, browser, browser-cache

When we open a specific website the browser caches the files and when next time we open the same website - Somehow browser fetches it from cache. I understand that the `.Cache` directory holds the information (probably in an encrypted way). I need to know is there any method or way by which we can extract the cached files (from some other website).

[image]

For example: Website A has cached files X. Now when we open website B in new tab somehow we should list down what are all the files which are cached in the browser currently.

If someone can help or guide where can we find the relevant document on this topic will be helpful?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use fetch for fetching the data from the browser cache, the first argument will have the name of the data resource you are looking for and the second argument specifies that the data should be fetched from the cache.

```js
 fetch("some.json", {cache: "force-cache"})
    .then(function(response)
```

Comment: Thanks Nikhil for quick response. Fetch API will fetch from the server as well (if not found in cache). My query is somehow similar to Fetch API but should only fetch from browser cache and return null or error if not found. Secondly, assuming we don't know the URL then it should list down all the cached files.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to **ONLY** pull from the cache, you can use "*only-if-cached*" for the cache property in the fetch:

```
fetch("some.json", {cache: "only-if-cached"})
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

If there is no match in the cache, the browser responds with a 504 Gateway timeout.

You can find more information here: [only-if-cached](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/cache)